# Firebase "OnCompleteListener" always returns successful

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my code the OnCompleteListener is always successful, even if I get my device offline, so the data cant get uploaded. How can I get the information that the data is not successful uploaded?

```
DatabaseReference index = database.getReference("Events").child(event_name).child("comments");
index.push().setValue(new Comment(newComment, userName)).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
        if(task.isSuccessful()){

            finish();

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: The task returned by setValue() should not complete successfully until the write reaches the server, however, the value will be visible from reads on the same device.  Are you sure you've tested this fully?

Comment: @DougStevenson Yeah I've tested it on multiple devices. All cut off from the internet but always successful return, but on the firebase database were not the new data. Obviously because the devices were cut off internet.

Comment: I don't observe this behavior at all.  Offline writes simply don't complete.

Comment: Thats what I expected but actually there is a other outcome.

Comment: If you have reproduction steps that anyone can follow, please file a bug report.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/